# how to define correctly textview width

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, sms

Hi everyone i got a little problem about the width of my textview
it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45pnh.jpg)

as you can see, my textview is bigger than my text :/

here is my code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="destinataire"
        android:id="@+id/tv_destinataire"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="envoyeur"
        android:id="@+id/tv_envoyeur"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

i would like something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU5oc.jpg), if the message contain some word well "wrap_content" whereas is long long message something like maximum 70% of width :

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can reach what you said adding some logic directly on your activity and not in the XML file. You can set the width by Java code with something like:

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

where myTextView is the id that you declared in your XML.

Now go ahead and write some logic...
If is necessary:

```
t.setWidth(200);
```

Note that 200 is only an example, you can calculate the width you need before.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I might use the relative layout and add maxWidth limit to TextView containing text, and as the dialog going, just place the TextView below the last TextView and use alignStart/alightParentStart and alignEnd/alignParentEnd to indicate who's speaking.

when a new message arrives

1. prepare your relative layout parameter, add layout rules
2. set text, maxwidth limit, layout parameter and other style you want for your text
3. add the view to a scrollable relative layout container

Sorry for my bad English in case of you have any reading problem. :)